# Array Constants (Fields) as Annotation Values

Tags: java, arrays, annotations, compile-time-constant

While this code happily compiles (with Java 8 / Eclipse Compiler)

```
public @interface specialized
{
    public Class[] value() default { int.class, long.class, float.class, double.class };
}
```

Refactoring it to use a constant instead of an array causes an error:

```
public @interface specialized
{
    public static final Class[] COMMONS = { int.class, long.class, float.class, double.class };

    public Class[] value() default COMMONS;
                                // ^ The value for annotation attribute specialized.value must be a class literal
}
```

I know that annotation values and -defaults have to be compile-time constants, but although the `COMMONS` array *is* technically a compile-time constant, why does this code cause an error? Personally, I think this is extremely counter-intuitive, as it is actually not too much of a pain for the compiler to simply inline this array.

I just realized that they (unsurprisingly) don't work as annotation *values* either, while they work in both cases in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COMMONS` is an array and therefore not a [compile-time constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Only strings and primitives can be part of compile-time constant expressions. You have to consider that a `static final` array is still mutable.

The default value in the example is not a standard array, it's a special language construct called `ElementValueArrayInitializer` ([JLS 9.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1)).

Comment: But for some reason directly using an array as the annotation value or `default` makes it count as one, so why can't the compiler 'de-reference' the constant field here and inline it's value? This works for `int` or `String` fields as well, so why not for arrays?

Comment: Scala can do this, and even my *little* programming language compiler can do it, so it doesn't seem like a hard thing to do, and the Bytecode also supports it. To me, this seems like either a compiler bug or, more realistically, an error in the spec.

Comment: @Clashsoft well, I suggest to submit a bug [here](http://bugreport.java.com/). As far as this site concerns, your question is solved with this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted it as a Requested javac Feature. Case closed.